# What is correct apache rewrite rule ( in .htaccess ) for coexist CodeIgniter and PhpBB3.1.X?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, phpbb

First i have my application run with CodeIgniter in directory /
Secondly I want install PhpBB forum in my subdir /forum/

But actually I have error 404 in /forum/install/app.php/install, i think it's due apache rewrite rules.
.htaccess :
In dir / ( for CodeIgniter ) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|assets|forum|images|cache)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in subdir /forum/ ( for phpBB )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine on

#
# Uncomment the statement below if URL rewriting doesn't
# work properly. If you installed phpBB in a subdirectory
# of your site, properly set the argument for the statement.
# e.g.: if your domain is test.com and you installed phpBB
# in http://www.test.com/phpBB/index.php you have to set
# the statement RewriteBase /phpBB/
#
RewriteBase /forum/

#
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
#
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

#
# The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
# to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
# by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
# /my/controller
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

#
# If symbolic links are not already being followed,
# uncomment the line below.
# http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/mod_rewrite-forbidden-403-with-apache-228/
#
#Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>
```

So «What is correct apache rewrite rule ( in .htaccess ) for coexist CodeIgniter and PhpBB3.1.X ?»

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Could anyone help me pleaze ?